# Passing Query params in Django Class Based View

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to form a url like this,
`http://localhost:8000/mealplan/meals/search/2?from_date=2019-12-29&to_date=2019-12-30&from_time=06:00&to_time=22:00`

This is what I tried in urls.py

```
    url(r'^meals/search/(?P<user_id>[\w.-]+)/(?P<from_time>[\w.-]+)/(?P<to_time>[\w.-]+)/(?P<from_date>[\w.-]+)/(?P<to_date>[\w.-]+)$', FilterMealList.as_view(), name='filter_meals'),
```

Clearly this didn't work. I got a 404, url doesn't exist on postman.
Also this is my class based view.

```
class FilterMealList(views.APIView):
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        try:
            from_time, to_time, from_date, to_date = kwargs.get('from_time'), kwargs.get('to_time'), kwargs.get(
                'from_date'), kwargs.get('to_date')
            return Response({"Suceess": "{}, {}, {}, {}".format(from_time, to_time, from_date, to_date)},
                            status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except KeyError as e:
            return Response({"Failure": "Incomplete query params"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

So my question,
1. How do I define an url to take query params in django?
2. How do I capture the params in my class based view?

How can I create an url to take query params in django

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `request.GET` to get a dictionary of the query params. The params shouldn't be defined in `urls.py`.

See the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET.

Comment: So what should the structure of my url be?

Comment: Something like this: `url(r'^meals/search/(?P<user_id>[\w.-]+)$', FilterMealList.as_view(), name='filter_meals'))`

Comment: It shouldn't need to make any reference to the query params.

Answer (score 5):

The part after the *question mark* is called the *querystring*. It is processed and available as a dictionary-like object (a `QueryDict`) in `self.request.GET`.

You thus define as path

```
url(r'^meals/search/(?P<user_id>\d+), FilterMealList.as_view()),
```

and in your view, you thus can filter with:

```
class FilterMealList(views.APIView):

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        user_id = self.kwargs['user_id']
        from_time = self.request.GET.get('from_time')
        to_time = self.request.GET.get('to_time')
        from_date = self.request.GET.get('from_date')
        to_date = self.request.GET.get('to_date')
        # …
```

Comment: Hi Willem, Can you please explain why did you use  `self.kwargs['user_id']` to get `user_id`  but `self.request.GET.get` for other parameters?

Comment: @haccks: because *path* parameters are put in `self.kwargs`, and the querystring in `self.reqest.GET`.

Comment: LoL, I am using DRF for writing REST APIs since past three years and I had no idea about this until yesterday I came to this post and then searched django and [DRF docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-the-url) and their source code. Finally learned there are two kind of URL parameters *path* and *querystring*. Feel like a noob here :). Thanks a lot by the way.

Comment: One more question, What parameters can we get in `args`? An example would be great.

Comment: @haccks If you used named capturing groups: nothing. `args` were from the days of `re_path()` when you could use an *unnamed* capturing group. These are discouraged by the official Django docs, as named URL parameters are much clearer.