# (Django) Trying to figure out how I can get the right product using query parameters on Postman (url.py and views.py)

Tags: python, django, http

I have been building a sandwich shop app and I succeesfully build models.py and inserted all the product data. However, when I try to call specific products using Postman and the Django server, it keeps showing 404. What I typed on postman is like so:
http://10.58.1.157:8000/product/sandwich?product_id=1

Below are my codes for urls.py and views.py

So far, I have tried:
urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ProductView

urlpatterns = [
    path('sandwich/int:<product_id>/', ProductView.as_view()),
]
```

and:
urls.py

```
path('sandwich/(?P<product_id>[\w.-]+)/', ProductView.as_view())
```

views.py

```
import json
import bcrypt
import jwt

from django.views               import View
from django.shortcuts           import render
from django.http                import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django.db.models           import Q

from .models                    import Product, Category, SubCategory

class ProductView(View):
    def get(self, request):

        product_id = request.GET.get('product_id', None)

        return JsonResponse({'product_name':Product.objects.get(id=product_id).values()})
```

To clarify the GET request, I will add the screenshot of Postman below:
[image: Postman screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue!

I looked at this page and improvised accordingly...
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#nested-arguments

the final version of request is:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/?product_id=1

and the urls.py is:

```
from django.urls        import path, re_path
from .views             import ProductView

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^(?:\?product_id=(?P<product_id>\d+)/)?$', ProductView.as_view()),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this is due to malformed `URL` path. That's whats typically indicative of `404-NotFound` error.

You need to add *question mark* that essentially forms the *querystring*. It is processed and available as a dictionary-like object (a `QueryDict`) in `request.GET` in `views.py`

You can define it like so, with a `?` using a `REGEX` pattern (You may also alter to your needs)

```
path('sandwich/(?P<product_id>[\w.-]+)/', ProductView.as_view()),
```

In your `views.py` you can filter them with

```
product_id = request.GET.get('product_id', None)
```

This should now hopefully return a response now that the `URL` cannot give a 404 error.

See [this for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59536294/passing-query-params-in-django-class-based-view)

Comment: I fixed my urls like you suggested but it's still not working somehow